# Notify on status of other operators in an Airflow DAG using Email Operator

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

Lets say I have a dag in airflow whose definition file looks like:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

default_args = {
    'owner' : 'airflow',
    'retries' : 0
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'email_notification_test',
    start_date = airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    default_args = default_args,
    schedule_interval = None,
    catchup=False
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id = 'start',
                        dag = dag)

def built_to_fail(ds, **kwargs):
    raise Exception('This operator fails')

def built_to_succeed(ds, **kwargs):
    print('This Operator succeeds')
    return

operator_that_fails = PythonOperator(
    task_id='operator_that_fails',
    python_callable=built_to_fail,
    dag = dag
)

operator_that_succeeds = PythonOperator(
    task_id='operator_that_succeeds',
    python_callable=built_to_succeed,
    dag = dag
)

email = EmailOperator(
    task_id='send_email',
    to='<email address>',
    subject='DAG Run Complete',
    html_content="""run_id: {{ run_id }} </p>
                    dag_run: {{ dag_run }} </p>
                    dag_run.id: {{ dag_run.id }} </p>
                    dag_run.state: {{ dag_run.state }}""",
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
    dag=dag
)

start >> [operator_that_fails, operator_that_succeeds] >> email
```

**DAG TLDR**: The dag has two operators, one which fails and one which succeeds. After both have finished executing, run a third task - an email operator - that sends a notification summary of the statuses of the preceding operators. For a visual aid, here is the webui graph view:

[image]

As I've demonstrated in the html_content part of the email operator, you can use jinja to reference objects and their attributes. What I really need though, is not only to report on the status of the dag itself, but of individual operators that have already run, so something like:

```
html_content="""operator_that_fails status : {{ <dynamic reference to preceeding task status> }} </p>
               operator_that_succeeds status: {{ <ditto for the other task> }}"""
```

I was trying to do this by exploring the Airflow object model documentation, ie. [this page for the "dag run" object](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html), but wasn't able to find a good way of getting preceeding task statuses.

Anyone know how best to achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use templating to access the context, like this:

```py
def contact_endpoints(**context):
    return ("subject text", "body text")

execute =  PythonOperator(
        task_id='source_task_id',
        python_callable=contact_endpoints,
        provide_context=True,
        do_xcom_push = True
    )

email = EmailOperator(
    task_id='send_mail',
    to="email@email.com",
    subject=f"""[{dag.dag_id}] {{{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='source_task_id', key='return_value')[0] }}}}""",
    html_content=f"""
        <br><br>
        <h3>Report</h3>
        {{{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='source_task_id', key='return_value')[1] }}}}
        """)
```

In my example, the task whose id is referenced in the xcom-pulls returns a tuple ("part to insert in subject", "part to insert in body").
You have to set do_xcom_push to true on the reference task.